# Can't convert iPad app to Mac App: Xcode couldn't find any Mac Catalyst App Development provisioning profiles matching 'maccatalyst.com...'

Tags: macos, ipad, code-signing, provisioning-profile, mac-catalyst

I'm trying to create a Mac Catalyst version of my iPad app. I checked the checkbox, I selected the "My Mac" scheme, I ran... and then, code signing errors (link below)!

[image]

When I checked the checkbox, the Signing & Capabilties tab added a new macOS platform entry, and a bundle identifier: maccatalyst.com.mycompany.myapp. That maccatalyst.com bundle ID isn't dispalyed in my Certifiicates, Identifiers & Profiles section of the Apple developer site. When I try to add it manually, by adding an App ID, choosing Mac and specifying the explicit bundle ID, I get the following error: An App ID with Identifier 'maccatalyst.com.mycompany.myname' is not available. Please enter a different string.

As suggested [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/123874), I also tried to:
1. Go to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles.
2. Select Profiles
2. Select iOS app that you are trying to catalyze from.
3. Enable "Mac".
4. Wait for hours.

How I have to proceed?

Comment: Hey, we are currently facing the exact same issue. Do you have made any progress on this?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet.

Comment: We ended up signing everything manually. This worked for us!

Comment: I did not get success when I do everything manually. see below Apple docs link. 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/mac_catalyst/replacing_the_mac_bundle_id_provided_by_xcode?language=objc

Answer (score 4):

We ended up signing everything manually following these steps:

1. Go to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles.
2. Select Identifiers
3. Select iOS app that you are trying to catalyze from.
4. Enable "Mac" and Save.
5. Go to Devices
6. Check if your Mac is added or add it
7. Go to Profiles
8. Create a "iOS App Development" provisioning profile using the previous App ID.
9. Create a "macOS App Development" provisioning profile using the previous App ID
10. Open XCode and select the target to catalyze
11. Enable Mac in General Tab
12. Go to Signin & Capabilities
13. Uncheck "Automatically manage signing"
14. Select iOS App Development Provisioning Profile under iOS platform
15. Select macOS App Development Provisioning Profile under macOS platform
16. Build and run

This worked for us!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Older version of Xcode 11.3.x or earlier, Just update to Xcode 11.4 or later then just Uncheck and check again this Mac device support.

[image: Uncheck and check this Mac device support]

Then go to Signing & Capabilities section, You can see that bundle identifier: `maccatalyst.com.mycompany.myapp` change to Use iOS Bundle identifier option.

[image: Use iOS Bundle identifier]

After that you can create macOS App Development Provisioning Profile under macOS platform using same Bundle identifie as iOS.

> NOTE: As of Xcode 11.4, new apps built with Mac Catalyst should use
>   the same bundle ID as the iOS app to support universal purchase or use
>   a manually-created unique bundle ID to be offered as a seperate
>   product. It is highly recommended that you continue developing any
>   in-progress apps built with Mac Catalyst using Xcode 11.4.

Check this link for more help:- https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev07ed024a6

Answer (score 0):

#### For 2022 ...  13.4

This may help someone.  As well as the excellent answer from @paolobriganti

Note that in fact

1. You **do** need to **create an app** on appstoreconnect, for the app in question. (Even if you never actually use that app listing.) Since your app will never be anywhere near the appstore, this seems counterintuitive. But if you want to use the automatic signing procedures, you need to do this. It seems, some say there's a way to get notarization without making an app on appstoreconnect, but we could not.
2. It does seem to be the case that you have to turn off (**ie, tap trash can**) on the "App Attest" item in Xcode.
3. Unfortunately I could NOT get the manual process to work. But the auto process works fine IF ...
4. You seem to have to **follow this order** ...

i. Restart Xcode and set a new bundle ID in Xcode (say com.company.attempt49)

ii. Automatically provision ... (note that com.company.attempt49 will now literally be on your appstoreconnect/developer.apple web site)

iii. AFTER that, in appstoreconnect, tap + and make a new app, using com.company.attempt49

iv. Only now, restart the mac (really)

v. Xcode, archive, and you should now be able to use the DeveloperID path, and get it notarized. The email arrives in a few minutes.

Although it makes no sense that you have to follow that order, it's often been the case in the past that apple automation is strangely fussy about the order in which steps are done.

---

***Critical dumb tip:***

It's really hard to find the "Export Notarized App" button in the Xcode organizer window. Once you tap on an archive It's at the extreme bottom right of the right-hand inspector-like panel. You won't see it unless you absolutely maximize the size of the organizer window :/